# Create model.matrix() from LASSO output

Tags: r, matrix, lasso-regression

I wish to create a model matrix of the independent variables/specific levels of categorical variables selected by LASSO so that I can plug said model matrix into a glm() function to run a logistic regression.
I have included an example of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
data("iris")
iris$Petal.Width <- factor(iris$Petal.Width)
iris$Sepal.Length2 <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length>=5.8,1,0)
f <- as.formula(Sepal.Length2~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width+Species)
X <- model.matrix(f,iris)[,-1]
Y <- iris$Sepal.Length2

cvfit <- cv.glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1,family="binomial")
fit <- glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1,family = "binomial")
b <- coef(cvfit,s="lambda.1se")
print(b)
## This is the part I am unsure of: I want to create a model matrix of the non-zero coefficients contained within 'b'
## e.g.
lasso_x <- model.matrix(b,iris)

logistic_model <- glm.fit(lasso_x,Y,family = "binomial")
```

Edit: 
I also tried the following:

```
model.matrix(~X)[which(b!=0)-1]
```

but it just gives me a single column of 1's, the length of the number of selections from LASSO (minus the intercept)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why do you want to make a model matrix of _coefficients_?

Comment: I want to make a model matrix of the variables that are selected by LASSO. for instance if a specific level of Petal.Width (e.g. Petal.Width=0.2) is selected by LASSO as being significant, I will have an associated column in my model matrix for Petal.Width=0.2 where a 1 denotes they have that petal width and 0 means that observation has a different width

Comment: do you want to refit a glm with the coefficients that are non-zero in lasso? you can just do model.matrix(f,iris)[,which(b!=0)] ? or is it something more complicated

Comment: that's it! thank you for the help, I knew i was getting close haha